# Split rows in multiple lines in oracle 11g and fetching in jsp

Tags: sql, oracle

The table is as follows:

```
+------------+--------------+
| product id | Rates        |
+------------+--------------+
| 108        | 10, 20, 30   |
+------------+--------------+
| 109        | 10,30        |
+------------+--------------+
```

I want to create the following:

```
+------------+--------------+
| Name       | Rates        |
+------------+--------------+
| 108        | 10           |
+------------+--------------+
|            | 20           |
+------------+--------------+
|            | 30           |
+------------+--------------+
```

I want like this in oracle 11g and I am fetching the row in jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this query :

```
WITH tab(product_id, Rates)  AS
(SELECT  108, '10, 20, 30' FROM dual UNION ALL 
 SELECT  109, '10,30'      FROM dual )
-------
--End of data
-------
SELECT CASE WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN product_id ELSE NULL END AS product_id, 
       regexp_substr(rates, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) rates
  FROM TAB
 CONNECT BY regexp_substr(rates, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
   AND PRIOR rates = rates
   and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

Output:

```
| PRODUCT_ID | RATES |
|------------|-------|
|        108 |    10 |
|     (null) |    20 |
|     (null) |    30 |
|        109 |    10 |
|     (null) |    30 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the table is called `product_rate`, query bellow may result the answer:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN product_id ELSE NULL END AS Name,
        regexp_substr(Rates, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) Rates
   FROM product_rate
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(regexp_replace(Rates, '[^,]+')) + 1;
```

[Sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c2922/14)

Comment: Its more recommended to do the thing in your user interface layer, BTW I have updated the answer.

Comment: i don't know how  to do in user interface..i am using jsp.